# How to search a string using one or more search words and add a string after each match?

Tags: php, search, preg-replace, str-replace, case-insensitive

Given a string with one or more search strings separated by a space, I would like to case-insensitively search for matches in a text.  When a match is found, I want to append `<-` immediately after the matched substring.

This is what I've tried:

**Code**

```
public function my_replace(string $fullText, string $searchText){

    $searches = explode(' ',$searchText);
    $replace = array();
    foreach ($searches as $i => $search){
        $replace[] = $search . '<-';
    }

    return str_ireplace($searches, $replace, $fullText);
}
```

**Example**

```
echo my_replace('A week ago, Elvis left the Building', 'elvis left');
```

**Output**

```
A week ago, elvis<- left<- the Building
```

**Desired output**

```
A week ago, Elvis<- left<- the Building
```

So I want to replace either `Elvis` or `elvis`, hence the `str_ireplace`, but on the output I want to show it the same way it was before.

**tldr;**

How do I replace a string with the same case letter if the string to replace with is actually not the same case? Does that even make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made some modification in your code itself,

This preg_replace will help you with your concern,

**Snippet**

```
function my_replace(string $fullText, string $searchText)
{
    $searches = explode(' ', $searchText);
    $replace  = array();
    foreach ($searches as $i => $search) {
        $fullText = preg_replace("/$search/i", "\$0<-", $fullText);
    }
    return $fullText;
}
echo my_replace('A week ago, Elvis left the Building', 'elvis left');
```

Here is working [demo](https://eval.in/1059620).

**Program Output**

> A week ago, Elvis<- left<- the Building

Answer (score 3):

Replacing a string will just replace with whatever you provided it with so `strireplace` will probably not work as you'd expect for your case.

In your particular use case you can instead manually search each of your text words for case insensitive search matches and update your text like below:

```
function my_replace(string $fullText, string $searchText){

    $searches = explode(' ',$searchText);

    $fullText = explode(' ', $fullText);

    $result = [];
    foreach ($fullText as $word) {
        $found = array_filter($searches, function ($search) use ($word) {
            return strcasecmp($word, $search) === 0;
        }); //If the array is not empty then $found is truthy otherwise its falsey
        $result[] = $word.($found ? "<-" : "");

    }
    return implode(" ", $result);

}

echo my_replace('A week ago, Elvis left the Building', 'elvis left');
```

This would echo:

> A week ago, Elvis<- left<- the Building

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3139650b0af1fa30712d05f2453b30b3cf66d5e1

Comment: Thank you! I went with @Rahul for the sake of simplicity! But I highly appreciate your code as well!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a single `preg_replace()` call with piped search strings, wordboundaries for accuracy, and a case-insensitive flag.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XER39))

```
function my_replace (string $fullText, string $searchText) {
    $searches = str_replace(' ', '|', $searchText);
    return preg_replace("/\b(?:$searches)\b\K/i", "<-", $fullText);
}
echo my_replace('A week ago, Elvis left the Building', 'elvis left');
```

Output:

```
A week ago, Elvis<- left<- the Building
```

The `\K` restarts the full string match.  So effectively, I tell `preg_replace()` to forget the entire match, but remember the end position -- that's where the `<-` goes.

The beauty is, no iterated function calls.  It's all done in one pass.

p.s. if your search strings are coming from users or otherwise untrusted sources, use `preg_quote()` to protect the regex pattern with escaping.

```
$searches = str_replace(' ', '|', preg_quote($searchText, "/"));
```

Comment: @PrimuS I post late answers when I can provide a superior snippet.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you like to insert '<-' after your searched word even the case is not same may be you can use any of the followings:-

using preg_match_all and preg_replace -

```
function my_replace(string $fullText, string $searchText){

    $searches = explode(' ',$searchText);
    $replace = array();
    foreach ($searches as $i => $search){
        preg_match_all('/'.$search.'/i',$fullText, $matches);
        if($matches){
            $fullText = preg_replace('/'.$search.'/i', $matches[0][0].'<-', $fullText);
        }
    }
    return $fullText;
}
```

Or by getting string position and insert '<-' at the calculated position

```
function my_replace(string $fullText, string $searchText){

    $searches = explode(' ',$searchText);
    $replace = array();
    foreach ($searches as $i => $search){
        $position = strlen($search)+stripos($fullText, $search);
        $fullText = substr_replace($fullText, '<- ', $position, 0);

    }
    return $fullText;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: There is too much that is not advisable about this answer.  Calling `preg_match_all()` and `preg_replace()` on every iteration is unnecessary overhead -- considering that `preg_match_all()` isn't needed at all (see my answer).  The declaration of `$i` is not necessary because it is never used.  Regex has capture groups so that you don't need to feed pre-generated variables as the replacement parameter.  Performing iterated calls of `preg_replace()` is unnecessary too (again, see my answer).  Your non-regex function fails when an unmatched search string occurs.  https://3v4l.org/TbOqp